# Search box feature for two fields to list customers

Tags: search

A friend of mine who I have built a Drupal site, wants a Search box feature on the Drupal homepage I.e Trade Search box, so a visitor can select a specific trade and area code and retrieve a list of tradesmen from the back-end not just the Content on the website per se.

I will need to populate the back-end with a list of trades and the Traders Post Code and make this accessible from the homepage with two search fields.

Is there a module as such, as the Search API module/views is the closest thing to what I am looking for?

Thanks